# Should I import 1 million rows at 1 time or import 1 million time 1 row to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I want to ask about the most effective way to import bulk data into CSV file

I have a relatively large CSV file, which has around 20 million rows, and I need to import them into MySQL. I know that there is a technique called LOAD DATA INFILE and many people see it as the fastest way to import bulk data in MySQl.

However, I want to ask whether there are any differences when I load 1 million rows at 1 time with 1 quarry versus when split the file and load to the database multiple times, for example 1 million or 100,000 or 10,000.

Comment: Inserting a single row would be much slower. LOAD DATA INFILE exists for a reason. It would seem to me that you could test this pretty quickly yourself with a temporary table and some sample data, couldn't you?

Comment: In a recent test, 100 million rows (6 columns) loaded into mySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE took around 6 minutes on a Mac (I don't know the specs). I loaded the same data in postgreSQL on an AMD Ryzen 3900x, 32 Gb in 4 minutes. So basically you can try yourself what happens if you load at once, split into 10 million rows files and load, and spilt into 10 million rows and load from multiple different threads.

Comment: You might like to read my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)